# Can I check a transaction before executing it?

Tags: solidity, ethers.js

Let's assume a contract has some state and functions which will alter that state. How could I check what the state of the contract will be after I execute a function before making the transaction?  (Assume nobody else is affecting the state of the contract)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you ask how to simulate a transaction off-chain. For this you have a couple tools. If you want the all in one hosted solution I would suggest you to look into https://tenderly.co/. If you have some programming knowledge you can also use [Ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/releases) to spin up a local for of a network and simulate your transaction. This will then allow you to inspect the state afterward. This can also be done with [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/) or [Brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

An example how Ganache can be used for transaction simulation can be found here: https://github.com/rmeissner/safe-simulator-gh-action/blob/main/src/simulator.ts